# Как связать две таблицы в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно связать фильм и пользователей, которые его смотрели. Думал насчет того, чтобы сделать связь "один ко многим" по id пользователей, но не уверен, что это будет правильно. Как будет правильно это реализовать?

Comment: "Многие ко многим". Потому что один фильм смотрит много пользователей и один пользователь смотрит много фильмов. Реализуется отдельной таблицей с двумя полями id-фильма и id-пользователя

Comment: @Mike а можете написать именно запросы, которые нужны?

Comment: Запросы для чего конкретно и кому они нужны ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого в MySQL есть джоины.

Псевдо-таблица:

```
- films
id | name
1 | Илетитсм. Ланиф

- views
film_id | user_id
1 | 1
```

Запрос к базе:

```
SELECT f.* FROM views AS v LEFT JOIN films AS f ON f.id = v.film_id WHERE v.user_id = 1
```

Comment: а можете объяснить для чего мы используем вот эту часть `f.id = v.film_id`

Comment: чтобы найти именно те фильмы, которые посмотрел юзер.
`WHERE v.user_id = 1` ищем все просмотры юзера 1, после у нас появляются ещё и айдишники фильмов, которые мы и выводим

Comment: а если у меня три таблицы ( 1 - все фильмы, 2 - все пользователи, 3 - все связи). Как мне вывести заменённые значения в 3 таблице на название фильмов и имена пользователей?

Comment: а там ведь продублированные значения будут. в каком формате вывод хочешь?

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо